# Multi Select Lookup is not working in crm 2011 after rollup12

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

This is not working after rollup 12.

```
var value = crmForm.all["new_state"].DataValue;
```

This syntax is working fine if I select single option but When I select more than one option in lookup it returns "undefined".

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_state").getValue();
```

Comment: I dont understand the question, are you telling us the second line doesnt work either?

Comment: 'Multi Select lookup' sounds unsupported to me - we will need to see more code. If you hit the DOM directly, I believe you are in unsupported territory, something that RU12 will likely show up very quickly.

Comment: Yes,Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_state").getValue(); doesnt work for me if I select more than one option.

Answer (score 0):

debug your website, try to see what do you have in:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_state")
```

Seems to me that you will have some array so to get the value of some array member you should write:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_state")[0].getValue()
```